# Visual Studio project. Extract source file folder name

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have this Visual Studio project. I use quite a few libraries.

For the sake of argument let's say I use one library and it is located over here:

> D:\lib-folder\main.cpp

And I have this source file:

> C:\source-folder\main.cpp

These source files get compiled down to `main.obj` files and are placed in the same folder:

> C:\Debug\main.obj

Linker starts complaining no doubt and there is no way I can compile my project. In the best case scenario I would like to extract the folder names of source files and place these `main.obj` files to these folders:

> C:\Debug\source-folder\main.obj
>
> C:\Debug\lib-folder\main.obj

How can I achieve this?

Comment: For which version of Visual Studios? You'll probably want to place the library in a separate project in the same solution from which you can compile it as a static library, then link it and set it as a dependency for your executable project

Comment: Those names only need to be different. You could use `C:\Debug\$(ProjectName)` for example.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `_getcwd` to get current the directory path of the .cpp file. Then you could extract the folder names of source files by intercepting the string. The following is an example:

```
char buf[_MAX_PATH];
_getcwd(buf, sizeof(buf));
string path = buf;
int start = path.rfind('\\');
cout << path.substr(start+1, path.size());
```

About how to put files in the specified folder, you could use [`MoveFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-movefile) function.